# Convert string timestamp mm/dd/yy hh:mm:ss to a date/time type in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, time, timestamp, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Row 1: cell A is a concat of the date in B and the time in C. I generate these with CTRL+: and CTRL+SHIFT+: respectively. Google sheets does not treat this like a timestamp on the x axis of charts

Row 2: I discovered CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+: to do a full timestamp, now it has a real timestamp

The issue is, I have many rows of recorded data of the type in Row 1 -- is there any way to convert this into a 'time' format that Google Sheets will respect on the x-axis of charts? Using VALUE() just gives the date portion of the timestamp.

Kind of crazy how much trouble this is causing me, is there really no date_parse(string_format) type function I can call?

EDIT:

this is ridiculous, just going to export and use python

[image: the two types I'm dealing with]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead `VALUE` use `TIMEVALUE` and then format it internally to time

or:

```
=TEXT(TIMEVALUE(A1); "hh:mm:ss")
```

for arrayformula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A="",,TEXT(TIMEVALUE(A1:A); "hh:mm:ss")))
```

for **timestamp > date** use `DATEVALUE`

Comment: Thanks, 
If I use TIMEVALUE for the time and the DATEVALUE for the date, how do I use them both to output a value with date and time in one cell as in A2 of the example i posted?

I tried: 
    =text(CONCAT(datevalue(A3), TIMEVALUE(A3)), "m/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss")

and it output '4/28/3102' for the date